# Jquery restart an animation after button click

Tags: jquery, html

I have a few lines of Jquery:

```
$(document).on('click', '#clicked', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".speech").css("animation-play-state", "running");
});

// Change text on click and reset animation
// 
$(document).on('click', '#clicked2', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.speech').each(function() {
        var text = $(this).text();
        $(this).text(text.replace('I AM A WOOKIE!!', 'YOU CLICKED!')); 
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
        var redo= $('.speech');
        $("." + redo.attr(".speech") + ":last").remove();  
        // $(".speech").remove();  
        $(".speech").css("animation-play-state", "paused");
    }, 2000);
});
```

How it works so far is that when you click #clicked an animation plays.

By then clicking #clicked2 it then changes the string from I AM A WOOKIE!! to YOU CLICKED!.

What I am then trying to achieve is after a timeout function it then resets back to the start of the original animation. So basically a reset button, but I am not sure how to get there.

The lines in question are:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var redo= $('.speech');
    $("." + redo.attr(".speech") + ":last").remove();  
    // $(".speech").remove();  
    $(".speech").css("animation-play-state", "paused");
}, 2000);
```

Everything else works as it should. I am just not sure on the correct syntax in order to reset my animation, so taht when you click #clicked again it is basically starting from the beginning

https://jsfiddle.net/uLg99tsw/8/

Comment: Prepare jsfiddle please and I will try to help you :) - joryl

Comment: Can you also provide the HTML codes or a JSFiddle demo to show the current situation as mentioned by Joryl? :)

Comment: Hi Sorry been away, will add a fiddle to the question

Comment: @factordog your fiddle doesn't seem to do anything? (Also might be a good idea to only add the relevant CSS to it)

Comment: He just forgot to include jQuery. Try this (including jQuery) https://jsfiddle.net/uLg99tsw/5/

Comment: updated the jquery for less CSS

Answer (score 0):

You are using `animation-play-state`. Why don't you use `transitions`? Take a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) and simply `add/remove` your transition CSS class to your markup on button click.

Comment: reason im not is im just practicing the concept of resetting variables and having them set to play again if the person were to go through the process a second or third time. Adding and removing classes is the ideal option but just for what im trying to learn and achieve this way is a bit more challenging

Answer (score 0):

I created a class `anim` then toggled it:

```
.anim {
  animation: talking 2s forwards;
}

$(document).on('click', '#clicked', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".speech").text("I AM A WOOKIE!!").toggleClass("anim");
});

$(document).on('click', '#clicked2', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".speech").text("YOU CLICKED!");
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qyo63ocs/)